# Field name in reusable macro

Tags: templating, macro

I'm creating a macro I'd like to reuse multiple times but the only thing that changes is the field name (matrix). Here's an example:

```
{% for block in entry.fieldname1 %}
<h3>{{ block.title }}</h3>
```

I'd like to increment this macro so I don't rewrite this code snippet over and over again but when I try and change **entry.fieldname1** to a string it's no`{% set string = entry.fieldname ~ 1 %}` it is no longer recognized inside the for loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using an array syntax instead of the object syntax:

```
{% set string = entry['fieldname' ~ 1] %}
```